# Load a .csv file from HDFS in Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs

So I basically have the following code to read a .csv file and store it in an `Array[Array[String]]`:

```
def load(filepath: String): Array[Array[String]] = {
      var data = Array[Array[String]]()
      val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile(filepath)
      for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines) {
        data :+ line.split(",").map(_.trim)
      }
      bufferedSource.close
      return data.slice(1,data.length-1) //skip header
  }
```

Which works for files that are not stored on HDFS. However, when I try the same thing on HDFS I get

> No such file or directory found

When writing to a file on HDFS I also had to change my original code and added some `FileSystem` and `Path` arguments to `PrintWriter`, but this time I have no idea at all how to do it.

I am this far:

```
  def load(filepath: String, sc: SparkContext): Array[Array[String]] = {
      var data = Array[Array[String]]()
      val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
      val stream = fs.open(new Path(filepath))
      var line = ""
      while ((line = stream.readLine()) != null) {
        data :+ line.split(",").map(_.trim)
      }

      return data.slice(1,data.length-1) //skip header
  }
```

This should work, but I get a `NullPointerException` when comparing line to null or if its length is over 0.

Comment: to read, use `sc.textFile` or `spark.read.csv`. To write use, `rdd.saveAsTextFile` or `df.write.save`

Comment: Thing is, I want to do it without Spark. You can ignore SparkContext. In my program, it is necessary to do it without Spark.

Comment: Put your code with FileSystem, Path, etc using Hadoop API

Comment: That is where I'm a little lost. Do I still use BufferedSource to read?

Comment: you use `fs.open` and the read the InputStream. where `fs` is `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`

Comment: I updated my question with how far I've come so far, I create the InputStream but not sure how to read it line by line.

Comment: you're close. Use `readLine` on your stream to read the file line by line.

Comment: readLine seems to be deprecated. Also when I try it anyways, I get NullPointerException at that line.

Comment: It's not deprecated. Read the documentation before you make claims like that. You get a nullpointerexception because the file was not read from hdfs. And you're still using Spark why? You can make a `Configuration` object without Spark libraries

Comment: readLine is crossed in my intelliJ, I'm using Scala 2.10.7. Anyways I'm trying different things, and always get nullpointer when comparing the var line = readLine(), for example if comparing it to null or checking if its length is over 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will read a .csv file from HDFS:

```
  def read(filepath: String, sc: SparkContext): ArrayBuffer[Array[String]] = {
      var data = ArrayBuffer[Array[String]]()
      val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
      val stream = fs.open(new Path(filepath))
      var line = stream.readLine()
      while (line != null) {
        val row = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
        data += row
        line = stream.readLine()
      }
      stream.close()

      return data // or return data.slice(1,data.length-1) to skip header
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Please read [this post about reading CSV](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/csv-file-how-to-process-open-read-parse-in-scala) by Alvin Alexander, writer of the Scala Cookbook:

```
object CSVDemo extends App {
  println("Month, Income, Expenses, Profit")
  val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("/tmp/finance.csv")
  for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines) {
    val cols = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
    // do whatever you want with the columns here
    println(s"${cols(0)}|${cols(1)}|${cols(2)}|${cols(3)}")
  }
  bufferedSource.close
}
```

You just have to get an InputStream from your HDFS and replace in this snippet

Comment: This is pretty much my initial method for reading a CSV file. I am having trouble reading the InputStream, read the updated question.

Comment: The question is also about reading a .csv. Otherwise it would not be on the title as it is not a relevant info. Thus, "Load a file from HDFS" should be the title

Comment: The title is clear, load a .csv file that is on hdfs. And you tried to answer it, although if you read my updated question you would see what I'm stuck at.